# "Пара минут"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "на это потребуется всего пар**у** минут" или "пар**а** минут"?

Comment: две минуты

Comment: Пара чулок или носков, например. Но не яблок или минут. Однозначно. Мне эти "пары" вместо 2 режут слух.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сочетание "пара минут" в данном контексте выступает как подлежащее, поэтому нужен именительный падеж: "*на это потребуется всего **пара** минут*". Винительный падеж необходим, например, в таком контексте: "*подожди **пару** минут*"

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее задуматься о том, что минуты — это не парный предмет.

Comment: Это отрезок времени, состоящий из двух совершенно одинаковых минут.
Пара - от (лат) par - равный.

Comment: Вообще-то я согласен с evgenii.
В том плане, что использование "пара" в занчении два и тем более "несколько" имеет не разговорный даже, а явно просторечный оттенок.

Answer (score 0):

А по немецки ein Paar,имя существительное,пишется с большой буквы,означает два парных предмета,а ein paar,наречие,-несколько предметов.

Comment: В русском языке пара - слово многозначное (в словаре указано 8 вариантов). Основным значением также являются два парных предмета, а пара минут - это разговорный вариант со значением "небольшое количество", также "пара яблок" - два яблока.

Comment: А как вам такие "разговорные слова"как звОнит,колидор,бИтон?Я так понял,что этот сайт о ГРАМОТНОМ русском языке,а не о просторечии.(в словаре"пара яблок"-просторечие.С уважением.

Comment: Интересное у Вас мнение о грамотности в русском языке. Мне кажется, что грамотность (в данном конкретном случае) заключается в умении правильно определить стилевую характеристику слова, в том числе указать разговорные, просторечные или ненормативные слова. Кстати, пара яблок дается в Грамоте.ру с пометкой (разг.). С уважением

Comment: В детстве одной из моих настольных книг была"Правильно ли мы говорим"Бориса Николаевича Тимофеева-Еропкина.Если не читали-прочтите,думаю,что не пожалеете.

Comment: Непременно прочту, если будет возможность. Только мне не очень понятен ваш переход от обсуждения темы к рекомендации книги. Чем конкретно мне может помочь уважаемый Б.Н. Еропкин? Если речь идет о речевых ошибках в нашем диалоге, пожалуйста, укажите на них.

Comment: Приведу пример.Две пары обуви или две пары яблок.Не видите разницу?Речь о речевых-по моему,это тавтология?Извините,если что не так.

Comment: ""Пара лет"не по русски".Это замечание сделал В.И.Ленин на рукописи одного автора.(Ленинский сборник,ХХV,стр.301.А чем пара минут отличается от пары лет,кроме временного отрезка,конечно?Хотя допускаю,что Ленин не является авторитетом в вопросе грамотности.Всегда с уважением.

Comment: Почем эти пряники? - Копейка пара (А. Чехов. Степь) .Что за безграмотная речь! Надо бы сказать: пряники в количестве двух штук будут стоить одну копейку. Но в целом ваша позиция мне понятна, всё яснее ясного. Ах да! Это же тавтология, или нет? Удивительная вещь - эта  тавтология! От речевой ошибки до художественного образа один шаг. Впрочем, приятно было познакомиться. Надеюсь, что в другой раз поговорим непосредственно на тему заданных вопросов.